# Getting Multiple Data Attributes

Tags: jquery, html

A bit difficult to explain....I'm trying to get the attribute of this repeating div. Code below..

```
<div class="hidden-data">
    <div class="menu-data" data-title="About"></div>
    <div class="menu-data" data-title="Team"></div>
    ETC/ETC/ETC
</div>
```

Right now I'm calling...

```
  var data = $(".menu-data").attr("data-title");
```

and only getting the first one, 'About'. I'd like to find a way to pass each 'data-title' attribute into an array.

Thoughts? I'm kind of stumped here, also having trouble Googling for this one..

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want those attributes to be returned as comma separated?

Comment: Was hoping i could get them into an array.

Answer (score 3):

Jquery

```
var array = [];
$(".menu-data").each(function() {
   array.push($(this).attr("data-title"));
});
```

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wxzuuj0L/)

Comment: You the man, Rex!! Thanks. Gotta work out my push muscles more!

Answer (score 0):

that's because when you call the data method on the jQuery object, it returns the data for the first element in the nodeList. To get the data for all the div's you have to loop through the elements with the `$.each` method or use a mapping to retrieve the attributes in a list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `eq` to get an equal that you want or use `each` to get each one

```js
 var data = $(".menu-data").eq(0).data('title');
  console.log('eq(0) : ' + data);
  
  var data = $(".menu-data").eq(1).data('title');
 console.log('eq(1): ' + data);
  
  $(".menu-data").each(function(){
  console.log('each: ' + $(this).data('title'));
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden-data">
    <div class="menu-data" data-title="About"></div>
    <div class="menu-data" data-title="Team"></div>
    ETC/ETC/ETC
</div>
```